# Masonry Plugin: Resizing div wont cause reshuffle

Tags: jquery, css, layout, jquery-masonry

Have Masonry items wrapped in 1000px wide div, I have a button to resize the div to 2000x using jQuery's `addClass()`, problem is Masonry won't reshuffle the items to fill the extra 1000px space, I know the resize works because resizing the browser window causes a reshuffle.

**Masonry:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.item',
        columnWidth : 240
    });
});
```

**Button:**

```
$("a.button").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("flip");
    $("div#container").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").addClass("resize");
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
width: 1000px; /* default */
width: 2000px !important; /* on button press */
```

I tried running ('a').click on the Masonry function using the same button, and it seems to work normally but the problem is still there.

Any advice? I'm stumped :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you need to run the masonry function agian when your re-size button is clicked.

```
$("a.button").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("flip");
    $("div#container").fadeOut("fast", function() {
    $(this).fadeIn("fast").addClass("resize");
    // run masonry again
    $('#container').masonry({      
      itemSelector : '.item',
      columnWidth : 240
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you have a method in mind? I had the default Masonry function run when the button was clicked, but the problem is still there, it's just inheriting what it was like before the resize, unless I resize the browser window. :/

Comment: also $("#container|).masonry("reload"); will achieve this

Answer (score 8):

From http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#reloaditems , calling `.masonry('reloadItems')` will grab (possibly new) items that match `itemSelector` and reposition the bricks, but calling `.masonry()` will just reposition items based on the most recent dimensions of its items.

Answer (score -2):

Try triggering the resize event with jquery:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

It worked for me!

Comment: This is a really poor way of triggering the reload functionality as it can cause the browser to repaint and trigger other resize listeners that don't need to be. Not to mention it's fragile since the resize listener on masonry can be disabled.