# Need help removing vertical space with divs in a grid

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I am working on a fluid grid section which displays events. I have media queries to adjust the size of the divs based on screen resolution. If all of the divs are the same height, it looks great. However, if they divs are different in height, the vertical space between them looks bad. I was wondering if there was a way to fix it. Not sure it can be done with css alone. Might need some javascript. I am attaching two images: one of what it looks like and one of what I want it to look like. HTML code is below.

```
<style>
body {
    background-color:#dedede;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px; 
}
#pagewrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.box {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
    margin:6px;
    max-width:220px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    background-color:#fff;
    float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .box {
        width:19%;
        margin:.5%;
    }
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .box {
        width:23.75%;
        margin:.5%
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .box {
        width:31%;
        margin:1%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 565px) {
    .box {
        width:46%;
        margin:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .box {
        width:90%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagewrap"> 
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultricesneque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus  posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus  Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdumneque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
<div class="box">Fusce ut sem est. In eu sagittis felis. In gravida arcu ut neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus rutrum non malesuada metus fermentum. Vestibulum neque ornare vitae rutrum turpis vehicula. Nunc ultrices sem mollis metus ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque interdum rutrum quam, a pharetra est pulvinar ac.</div>
</div>
</body>
```

What it currently looks like:
[image: what it looks like]
<sub>(source: [asingularcreation.com](http://asingularcreation.com/Images/test/bad.jpg))</sub>

What I want it to look like:
[image: what I want it to look like]
<sub>(source: [asingularcreation.com](http://asingularcreation.com/Images/test/good.jpg))</sub>

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to support only modern browsers, you could use [CSS3 multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS3_Columns).

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Dh/

```
#pagewrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    -webkit-column-width: 220px;
    -moz-column-width: 220px; 
    column-width: 220px; 
}
.box {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
    margin:6px;
    max-width:220px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    background-color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

However for a cross-browser solution there's the [Vanilla Masonry Library](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) if you are not using jQuery, or the [Masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html). Both does what you are looking for.

Comment: I love jquery. Thanks so much for your response. I will give it a try and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I tried the masonry jquery plugin and it worked ok, but not great. It is fine if the divs within them are a standard width and you are not worried about changing the width of the div based on screen resolution. But I didn't quite work as well as I want for what I need. Thanks again for the help. I will keep digging.

Comment: @singular, I believe that you would have to re-apply the plugin in case of a resize. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542846/masonry-plugin-resizing-div-wont-cause-reshuffle

Comment: Thanks again. After a bit more searching and experimenting,, I found the solution and will post it. I do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I found and works great.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var CollManag = (function() {
        var $ctCollContainer = $('#pagewrap'),
        collCnt = 1,
        init = function() {
            changeColCnt();
            initEvents();
            initPlugins();
        },
        changeColCnt = function() {
            var w_w = $(window).width();
            if( w_w <= 360 ) n = 1;
            else if( w_w <= 565 ) n = 2;
            else if( w_w <= 720 ) n = 3;
            else if( w_w <= 980 ) n = 4;
            else n = 5;
        },
        initEvents = function() {
            $(window).on( 'smartresize.CollManag', function( event ) {
                changeColCnt();
            });
         },
         initPlugins = function() {
            $ctCollContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $ctCollContainer.masonry({
                    itemSelector : '.box',
                    columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
                        return containerWidth / n;
                    },
                    isAnimated : true,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 400
                    }
                });
            });
            $ctCollContainer.colladjust();
            $ctCollContainer.find('div.box-multi').collslider();
        };
        return { init: init };
    })();
    CollManag.init();
 });
```